# I have a string "aabbbccdda" and i need the output to be "a2b3c2d2a1"

Tags: javascript, string

I have an Input string --> `aabbbccdda`
I need the below output --> `a2b3c2d2a1`

How can I achieve this result?

Comment: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have done this in java -

```java
public class ABPattern {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "aabbaaccd";
        char[] chars = str.toCharArray();
        int count;

        for(int i=0;i< chars.length;i++){
            count=1;
            for (int j=i+1;j< chars.length;j++){
                if(chars[i]==chars[j]){
                    count++;
                }else {
                    break;
                }
                i = j;
            }
            System.out.print(chars[i]+""+count);
        }
    }
}
```

and your output is a2b2a2c2d1